# Angular 14 issue in method loading component at runtime

Tags: angular, angular14

I am using Angular 14 and I'm trying to load a component at runtime like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      
      @ViewChild('dropdownComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef })
      
      dropdownComponent!: ViewContainerRef;
    
      constructor(private ref: ViewContainerRef) {}
    
      async loadit() { 
        const { DropdownComponent } = await import('./components/dropdown/dropdown.component');
        this.dropdownComponent.clear();
        this.dropdownComponent.createComponent(DropdownComponent); 
      }
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clear')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clear')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: At which point of time do you call `loadit()`? How does the template look like?

Comment: It's dangerous to use non-null-assertion `!` with `@ViewChild` because in reality it can totally happen that the view child is not available, due to timing and conditional rendering.

Comment: @JSONDerulo The component that I'm trying to load is an empty generated component..just a bit of text in it. This component is a standalone component (feature of NG14) and I want to lazy load it without routing ... You know another way to do this?

Comment: Could you show the relevant part of `app.component.html`?

Comment: It's just this: <button (click)="loadit()">LOAD IT</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into the [documentation of `ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild). You are using a string to select your view child, in this case you need a corresponding template reference variable. To create it, add something like the following to your `app.component.html`:

```
<div #dropdownComponent></div>
```